# Tag merge request: [metro-ui] and [metro]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

I don't see any need for the [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) tag. I think it should be merged with the [metro](/questions/tagged/metro) tag.

Comment: Considering the description is the same for both the tags, I would think there is no need to have two different tags.

Comment: Why did somebody downvote this question? Perfectly legitimate.

Comment: Just means they don't think the tags should be merged. Not that the question is badly written or anything. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: As unpopular as this was originally (and ultimately futile since MS changed the name anyway), the tags *were* merged at some point. Go figure.

Comment: @Shog9: Thanks, man. Like I said - I had the best of intentions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Before the release of Windows 8, there was a [metro](/questions/tagged/metro) tag. It was used for something to do with Java and Tomcat. People started using it for the Windows 8 Metro style anyway, which I think was the wrong choice. At some point the tag wiki was edited to describe the Windows 8 Metro content. That seems to have made [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) redundant; but what's happening to those questions tagged [metro](/questions/tagged/metro) that have nothing to do with Windows 8?

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615013/issue-in-adding-webservices-tool-in-here-in-jboss-studio
- [Generating web service client in netbeans in web application using maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585877/generating-web-service-client-in-netbeans-in-web-application-using-maven)
- [Difference between Jax-ws RI and metro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560080/difference-between-jax-ws-ri-and-metro)

These questions are drowned out by Windows 8 ones; but perhaps we should be retagging the [metro](/questions/tagged/metro) ones that are Windows 8 focused to use [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) instead.

Comment: So just to clarify, we'll use [metro-ui] for both Windows Phone apps and Metro-style apps in Windows 8, aye? I ask because someone has tagged a handful of questions with [metro-style-app], but I don't think we need another tag for the Metro design language shared by both platforms, and we have the [windows-8] and [winrt] tags for categorizing those particular questions anyway.