# Consensus on taxonomy for Windows Phone, Windows 8, and things named Metro?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

A few days ago, somebody went to tag a handful of questions with [metro-style-app](/questions/tagged/metro-style-app). Don't we already have the [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) tag for Metro apps, and both [windows-8](/questions/tagged/windows-8) and [winrt](/questions/tagged/winrt) for apps specifically designed for Windows 8? Or do we need that new tag to distinguish Metro-style apps on Windows 8 from Windows Phone apps (that are all in the Metro style anyways)?

Can we come to a consensus on what tags we should use for Windows Phone apps, Metro-style apps on Windows 8, the Metro design language, and anything else named Metro so we don't end up with a bunch of ambiguous and superfluous tags? Now would be a good time to nip this issue in the bud; I don't want this to get out of control when more questions surface in the very near future (i.e. when [Visual Studio 11 beta](https://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/visual-studio-11) drops next week).

Some related discussions:

- [Should the "metro" tag refer to a Java framework or Windows 8 technology?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120158/should-the-metro-tag-refer-to-a-java-framework-or-windows-8-technology)
- [Windows 8 and related tags need a little love](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106716/windows-8-and-related-tags-need-a-little-love)

Comment: This is like C++11 all over again... The people doing the tagging just don't understand the intricacies and nuances of the various product names, and the people who *do* understand who would ordinarily propose and approve tag synonyms quibble over the fact that they're not entirely synonymous... I say so what, but I'm a radical.

Answer (score 4):

I've been retagging [metro](/questions/tagged/metro) to [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) when it's clearly a Windows 8 kind of question. I've been utterly ignoring [metro-style-app](/questions/tagged/metro-style-app) and think it should be synonymed away. I don't think it needs to be looked at question-by-question as the metro ones do. I have a tag score of 2 in [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) so I don't get to propose synonyms. I don't feel bad, the top user of all time has a tag score of 19 and second place is 12. But anyway, I'm not going to [go into that again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100948/what-part-of-tag-score-do-i-not-understand-yet).

Comment: Agreed on making them synonyms, since I believe Metro UI is Metro UI as far as Microsoft is concerned. I've gone ahead and merged them, with [metro-ui] as the master tag.